# PHPStorm Sync With Deployed Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: phpstorm

Just started using PHPStorm and I like the FTP sync function that's built-in.  Is there a way for me to have the "Sync With Deployed mywebsite.com" screen pop-up using a keyboard short-cut?  If not, any way I can bind a set of keys for this task?  Thanks!

Comment: If that server marked as default for that project -- then yes. If you need to deploy the same code to different servers (not default one) then you cannot assign separate shortcut to specific server directly -- see CarzyCoder's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to assign a keyboard shortcut directly for the server specific synchronization action, only for the generic `Sync with Deployed to...` action that will show a pop-up with the list of configured servers. If you have only one server, just confirm it with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or a number.

However, you can record a Macro:

1. `Edit` | `Macros` | `Start Macro Recording`.
2. `Tools` | `Deployment` | `Sync with Deployed to <server name>`, close the sync window.
3. `Edit` | `Macros` | `Stop Macro Recording`.
4. Set macro name to something like `Sync with <server name>`.
5. Go to `File` | `Settings` | `Keymap`, under `Macros` node right click on the new sync macro that you've just recorded and `Add keyboard shortcut`.

Comment: How would I assign a shortcut for the generic "Sync with Deployed to" action?

Comment: Exactly like you would do for any other action, hope [this screenshot will help](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/2668/20130211045108.png).